# Slow query - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: performance, optimization, postgresql-9.2, query-performance

I've got a Query that takes some time to be executed...
Can you guys help to improve the total time?

Thank you!

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT
  file.inode_id        AS file_id,
  file.parent_inode_id AS file_group,
  file.relative_path   AS file_type,
  file.file_data       AS file_binary,
  file.node_full_path  AS file_name,
  file.last_modified   AS date_created
FROM
  gorfs.nodes AS file
  INNER JOIN
  gorfs.inode_segments AS iseg ON iseg.st_ino = file.parent_inode_id
                                  AND file.object_type = 'S_IFREG'
                                  AND iseg.nfs_migration_date IS NULL
                                  AND (file.last_modified <
                                       (transaction_timestamp() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - '1 months' :: INTERVAL))
                                  AND iseg.st_ino_target = file.inode_id
LIMIT
  100;
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE:**

```
"Limit  (cost=1065462.16..3016209.40 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=228236.454..229186.199 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1065462.16..3016209.40 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=228236.452..229185.915 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1065462.16..3016024.51 rows=1 width=114) (actual time=228186.392..228761.705 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (("iseg"."st_ino")::bigint = ("p"."st_ino")::bigint)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1065462.16..2333068.00 rows=45380 width=36) (actual time=228148.879..228395.996 rows=100 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (("t"."st_ino")::bigint = ("iseg"."st_ino_target")::bigint)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=333953.51..1414706.48 rows=13556296 width=20) (actual time=3235.704..3358.321 rows=12534 loops=1)"
"                          ->  CTE Scan on "stat_h_with_bits" "sb"  (cost=519.00..519.52 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.242..0.242 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ("constant_name" = 'S_IFREG'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3"
"                                CTE stat_h"
"                                  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.29 rows=23 width=68) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                                CTE stat_h_with_bits"
"                                  ->  CTE Scan on "stat_h" "s"  (cost=0.00..518.71 rows=23 width=68) (actual time=0.059..0.230 rows=4 loops=1)"
"                                        SubPlan 3"
"                                          ->  Aggregate  (cost=22.51..22.52 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=1 loops=4)"
"                                                ->  Function Scan on "regexp_split_to_table" "digits"  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.029 rows=6 loops=4)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "inodes" "t"  (cost=333434.52..1278623.99 rows=13556296 width=29) (actual time=3235.455..3327.013 rows=12534 loops=1)"
"                                Recheck Cond: ((B'00000000000000001111000000000000'::"bit" & ("st_mode")::"bit") = ("sb"."bits")::"bit")"
"                                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 50886"
"                                Filter: (("st_mtime")::timestamp without time zone < ("timezone"('UTC'::"text", "transaction_timestamp"()) - '1 mon'::interval))"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_inodes_file_type_bits"  (cost=0.00..330045.44 rows=13561379 width=0) (actual time=3155.907..3155.907 rows=6197466 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: ((B'00000000000000001111000000000000'::"bit" & ("st_mode")::"bit") = ("sb"."bits")::"bit")"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=727709.45..727709.45 rows=303936 width=16) (actual time=224676.365..224676.365 rows=40682315 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 32768  Batches: 128 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 16385kB"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "inode_segments" "iseg"  (cost=5698.42..727709.45 rows=303936 width=16) (actual time=16602.138..137542.019 rows=60787133 loops=1)"
"                                Recheck Cond: ("nfs_migration_date" IS NULL)"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "ix_inode_segments_nfs_migration_date"  (cost=0.00..5622.44 rows=303936 width=0) (actual time=16513.399..16513.399 rows=60787133 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: ("nfs_migration_date" IS NULL)"
"              ->  Index Scan using "ix_inode_segments_st_ino_targets" on "inode_segments" "p"  (cost=0.00..15.04 rows=1 width=86) (actual time=3.647..3.649 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                    Index Cond: (("st_ino_target")::bigint = ("t"."st_ino")::bigint)"
"        ->  Index Scan using "pk_inodes" on "inodes" "i"  (cost=0.00..13.21 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.445..2.457 rows=1 loops=100)"
"              Index Cond: (("st_ino")::bigint = ("p"."st_ino")::bigint)"
"              Filter: ((("st_ino")::bigint = 2) OR ((B'00000000000000001111000000000000'::"bit" & ("st_mode")::"bit") = B'00000000000000000100000000000000'::"bit"))"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Aggregate  (cost=171.66..171.67 rows=1 width=574) (actual time=1.770..1.771 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                ->  Index Scan using "ix_inode_segments_st_inos" on "inode_segments" "fs"  (cost=0.00..171.55 rows=40 width=574) (actual time=1.741..1.750 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                      Index Cond: (("st_ino")::bigint = ("p"."st_ino_target")::bigint)"
"Total runtime: 229530.743 ms"
```

**INDEX ix_inode_segments_nfs_migration_date:**

```
CREATE INDEX ix_inode_segments_nfs_migration_date
  ON gorfs.inode_segments
  USING btree
  ("nfs_migration_date")
  WHERE "nfs_migration_date" IS NULL;
```

**Table: gorfs.inode_segments:**

```
CREATE TABLE gorfs.inode_segments
(
  st_ino "gorfs"."ino_t" NOT NULL, -- Inode number the segment belongs to. alongside segment_index, it forms the table's primary key to ensure uniqueness per relevant scope
  segment_index "gorfs"."pathname_component" NOT NULL, -- See st_no's column description for further details. The meaning of this column varies based on the host inode type:...
  st_ino_target "gorfs"."ino_t", -- Target inode number. Meaningful for directory inode segments (objects in the directory)
  full_path "gorfs"."absolute_pathname", -- Exploded absolute canonical path for quick lookups. Meaningful only for directory inode segments (objects in the directory)
  segment_data "bytea", -- Actual data segment. Meaningful only for S_IFLNK and S_IFREG....
  nfs_migration_date timestamp with time zone,
  nfs_file_path "text",
  CONSTRAINT pk_inode_segments PRIMARY KEY ("st_ino", "segment_index"),
  CONSTRAINT fk_host_inode_must_exist FOREIGN KEY (st_ino)
      REFERENCES gorfs.inodes (st_ino) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_target_inode_must_exist FOREIGN KEY (st_ino_target)
      REFERENCES gorfs.inodes (st_ino) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uc_no_duplicate_full_paths UNIQUE ("full_path"),
  CONSTRAINT cc_only_root_can_be_its_own_parent CHECK ("st_ino_target" IS NULL OR "st_ino"::bigint <> "st_ino_target"::bigint OR "st_ino"::bigint = 2)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

**View: gorfs.nodes:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gorfs.nodes AS 
 SELECT "p"."full_path" AS "node_full_path", "h"."st_ino" AS "parent_inode_id", 
    "t"."st_ino" AS "inode_id", 
        CASE
            WHEN "p"."st_ino_target"::bigint = 2 THEN NULL::character varying
            ELSE "p"."segment_index"::character varying
        END AS "relative_path", 
    "t"."st_mode"::bigint AS "raw_mode", "f"."constant_name" AS "object_type", 
    ("gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_ISUID'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit" & "t"."st_mode"::"bit")::integer <> 0 AS "setuid", 
    ("gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_ISGID'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit" & "t"."st_mode"::"bit")::integer <> 0 AS "setgid", 
    ("gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_ISVTX'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit" & "t"."st_mode"::"bit")::integer <> 0 AS "sticky", 
    "right"("concat"((("gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_IRWXU'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit" | "gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_IRWXG'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit") | "gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_IRWXO'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit") & "t"."st_mode"::"bit"), 9)::bit(9) AS "permissions", 
    "t"."st_nlink" AS "links_count", "t"."st_uid" AS "owner_uid", 
    "t"."st_gid" AS "owner_gid", "t"."st_size" AS "data_length", 
    "t"."st_atime" AS "last_accessed", "t"."st_mtime" AS "last_modified", 
    "t"."st_ctime" AS "last_changed", "t"."checksum_md5", 
    ("mst"."media_type" || '/'::"text") || "mst"."subtype_string"::"text" AS "media_type", 
        CASE
            WHEN "f"."constant_name" = 'S_IFLNK'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name" THEN ( SELECT "convert_from"("ls"."segment_data", 'UTF8'::"name") AS "convert_from"
               FROM "gorfs"."inode_segments" "ls"
              WHERE "ls"."st_ino"::bigint = "p"."st_ino_target"::bigint)
            ELSE NULL::"text"
        END AS "target", 
        CASE
            WHEN "f"."constant_name" = 'S_IFREG'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name" THEN ( SELECT "string_agg"("fs"."segment_data", ''::"bytea" ORDER BY "fs"."segment_index") AS "string_agg"
               FROM "gorfs"."inode_segments" "fs"
              WHERE "fs"."st_ino"::bigint = "p"."st_ino_target"::bigint)
            ELSE NULL::"bytea"
        END AS "file_data", 
    "t"."external_size" IS NOT NULL AS "is_external", 
    "t"."external_size" AS "data_length_target"
   FROM "gorfs"."inode_segments" "p"
   JOIN "gorfs"."dir_inodes" "h" ON "h"."st_ino"::bigint = "p"."st_ino"::bigint
   JOIN "gorfs"."inodes" "t" ON "t"."st_ino"::bigint = "p"."st_ino_target"::bigint
   JOIN "gorfs"."mode_t_flags"() "f"("constant_name", "description", "bits", "bits_octal", "bits_hex", "bits_decimal") ON "f"."bits"::"bit" = ("gorfs"."mode_t_bits"('S_IFMT'::"gorfs"."mode_t_constant_name")::"bit" & "t"."st_mode"::"bit")
   LEFT JOIN "media_subtypes" "mst" ON "mst"."media_subtype_id" = "t"."media_subtype_id";
```

**UPDATED**:
I've created the INDEX:

```
create index concurrently inode_segments_st_ino_target_pidx on gorfs.inode_segments (st_ino desc, st_ino_target desc) where nfs_migration_date is null;
```

**NEW EXPLAIN ANALYZE:**
http://explain.depesz.com/s/Swu